# Dynamic resource from MemoryStream with ResourceWriter

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm developing an app with C# and WPF;
I'm creating a resource to a MemoryStream.

```
var ms = new MemoryStream();
var rWriter = new ResourceWriter(ms);

rWriter.AddResource("key1", "value1");
rWriter.AddResource("key2", "value2");
rWriter.AddResource("key3", "value3");

rWriter.Generate();
rWriter.Close();
```

Everything works fine untill here but, I don't know how to use this Resource?
Can you help me with using ?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am creating this resource from a encrypted text file. İ decrypt it and create this resource. And, i need to reach the values that i have added to resource.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have read the resource into the stream you need to add it to the MergedDictionaries in order to make it available in the application.  An example of this might look like this:

```
var resourceInfo = skinAssembly.GetManifestResourceInfo(resourceName);
if (resourceInfo.ResourceLocation != ResourceLocation.ContainedInAnotherAssembly)
{
    var resourceStream = skinAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName);

    using (var resourceReader = new ResourceReader(resourceStream))
    {
        foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in resourceReader)
        {
            if (IsRelevantResource(entry, bamlResourceName))
            {
                skinBamlStreams.Add(entry.Value as Stream);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code above was taken from my demo application which you can see the full source code for on [GitHub](https://github.com/jamsoft/WPF-Prism-Demo-Part2).

```
protected override sealed void LoadResources()
{
    var skinResolver = PreLoadResources();
    try
    {
        var skinBamlStreams = skinResolver.GetSkinBamlStreams(_fullName, _resourceName);
        foreach (var resourceStream in skinBamlStreams)
        {
            var skinResource = BamlHelper.LoadBaml<ResourceDictionary>(resourceStream);
            if (skinResource != null)
            {
                Resources.Add(skinResource);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        PostLoadResources();
    }
}
```